# how to run a parallel query on sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i want to run a query on multiple processors. what is the syntax to run a parallel query? please provide a sample query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't: the optimizer decides based on the "cost" of the query (and some other factors)

See BOL: [Parallel Query Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065.aspx)

Now, you can limit parallelism with MAXDOP or change the cost threshold, but it's not something I'd do.

Why do you want to explicitly set this?

Comment: i know but i was checking this thread at msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175097.aspx they are showing an example of running a parallel query but i didnt get it

Comment: They are showing a query which happens to be using parallelism at that time. The plan that they show is what the engine determined was best. They didn't do anything specific to cause it.